# What are radio_dump .bin files? Can I delete them?

Tags: cellular-radio

Each radio_dump_xxxxxxx.bin is 37MB in size.

Comment: I don't think your Windows computer will need them. </Sarkasm> Could you give a few more details, e.g. where exactly they are located? As your question is phrased currently, it's hard to answer.

Comment: Keeping the question open. It can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

According to an [XDA post](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=14476628&postcount=19107), it means that your modem crashed. They are safe to delete. BUT, you may want to consider changing/upgrading the radio/modem for your phone.